# How can I add an HTML element without affecting the position of existing content?

Tags: html, css

For example, suppose I have the following simple page

```
<h3>Hi!</h3>
<img src="http://www.thehindu.com/multimedia/dynamic/01338/IN__GOOGLE__1338298f.jpg">
```

If I had add a link as follows:

```
<a href="#">my link</a>
```

It will appear bottom right next to the image. What CSS do I use to make the link appear at the top right of the page without affecting any of the other elements of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean, top right of the page without making it follow, you need `position: absolute` on the element with `top: 0; right: 0;`. This will position it to the top-right of the first element in your DOM tree (moving upwards) that has a CSS `position` that is not `static` - usually ends up being on the `body` if you haven't done anything fancy.

If you do want to make it follow your screen: `position: fixed` with `top: 0; right: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning by giving it this CSS style:

```
position:absolute; top:0; right:0;
```

Inline by using a style attribute or in an external style sheet using some selector to target the link.

Inline example:

```
<a href="#" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;
">my link</a>
```